# How to "source" VsDevCmd.bat in a MSYS2 bash shell?

Tags: bash, visual-studio, shell, msys2

How can I enter the Visual Studio Developer Prompt within a bash shell on MSYS2? The goal is to get the environment setup, so all the build tools that get installed for Visual Studio get available on the command line.

The goal is also to not end up in a `cmd.exe` prompt, because I would lose all my bash aliases and functions.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot source `.bat` files, because sourcing will be done by `bash` and it expects bash code, not batch code. The right command on the `cmd` side would be `call`, but `call` is an internal command which is not available in `bash`.

The trick is to spawn a `cmd` with `//c` (MSYS2 converts this to `/c`) and then giving the path and arguments, which looks pretty sophisticated as an alias:

```bash
export VS_DEFAULT_VERSION="2022"
alias vsdevcmd='{ f() { cmd //k "$(cygpath -wF 38)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\${1:-$VS_DEFAULT_VERSION}\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat" -startdir=none -arch=x64 -host_arch=x64 \&\& bash; }; }; f'
```

It allows to spawn a developer prompt for any version by providing the year, such as `vsdevcmd 2022`, but it falls back to `2022` when the argument is dropped.

It assumes the architecture x64 and the Community version.

Since exiting the `cmd` would mean to lose the environment again, we simply choose to open `bash` in `cmd` again by passing `&& bash` escaped to the `cmd`.

Since you run `vsdevcmd` in `bash`, its `PATH` environment is passed down to `cmd` which allows you to go back into `bash` again, but this time all the environment is set up for Visual Studio tooling.

This solution was tested in Git for Windows SDK (`winget install Git.SDK`).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function `f` and an alias, simply define a function :

```
VS_DEFAULT_VERSION=2022
vsdevcmd(){
    local v=${1:-$VS_DEFAULT_VERSION}
    cmd /C "$(cygpath -wF 38)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\$v\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat"\
        "&&" bash
}
```

(or //C if need be)

Comment: Thanks, yes, a function is cleaner, I wrapped a function in an alias to make it shorter. I wouldn't make it longer and keep it an alias though. Btw `local` is not `POSIX` compliant, for `bash` it doesn't have to, but I do it anyways.

Comment: If I write as a one-liner, my version is even shorter than yours, which would be less readable. As for `local`, you can use `declare` if you want POSIX compliance.

Answer (score 0):

You start the VS Developer Prompt first, and then launch MSYS2 from it with `-full-path` to make it inherit the PATH (other vars are always inherited, I believe), e.g.:

```
C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -full-path -ucrt64
```